# EF Core 7 to multiple delete the entity without primary key, using other columns of table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I have a method shown below, where I am attaching `AuthorityProvisionId`, `IssueId` and `TenantId` to the entity type `IssueProvision`. I am not setting the `Id` because I need to make database call to get the Id of the entity.

I am trying to delete the entity based on these properties `AuthorityProvisionId`, `IssueId` and  `TenantId`

```
public async Task BulkDeleteIssueProvision(List<IssueProvision> issueProvision)
{
        if (issueProvision is {Count: > 0})
        {
            var dbContext = GetDbContext();
            EntityEntry<IssueProvision> issueProvisionDbContext = null; 

            foreach (var issueProvisionList in issueProvision)
            {
                issueProvisionDbContext = dbContext.Attach(new IssueProvision
                {
                    AuthorityProvisionId = issueProvisionList.AuthorityProvisionId,
                    IssueId = issueProvisionList.IssueId,
                    TenantId = issueProvisionList.TenantId
                });
            }

            issueProvisionDbContext.State = EntityState.Deleted;
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); 
        }
}
```

However, when trying to delete the entity it's throwing an exception:

> The property 'IssueProvision.Id' has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Deleted'. Either set a permanent value explicitly, or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.

I know this issue is related to the primary key of the table. The question is how can I delete multiple data without the primary key of the entity.

Comment: You can't do it without the primary key

Comment: Not quite clear to me; either you **have stored** that entity in the database already, but then you **must have** a primary key - or you haven't stored the entity into the database yet - so just don't call `.SaveChanges()` and just don't store it in the first place - why "delete" it, if it hasn't been stored ....

Comment: @marc_s I already have a set of data in the Db, but I don't want to make the multiple calls to the DB to get the Id of each record because I have three properties as condition

Comment: You could run an [ExecuteDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates) statement for each record.